# Xcode 7 - macro name must be an identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've upgraded to Xcode 7 and out of the sudden one of my targets fails to build with "macro name must be an identifier" message. Debug configuration of this target builds just ok and I can run it on the device, but release configuration doesn't build.

The error points to the target's .pch file, but same .pch file builds just ok for many other targets, including those that are release.

Here is the error message:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/speedometer-Prefix-copscroeimdxfkdvcsfifjmzires/speedometer-Prefix.pch.pch speedometer/speedometer-Prefix.pch normal armv7 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Documents/code/speedo
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DTAXI -D=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Intermediates/speedo.build/Release-iphoneos/taximeter.build/taximeter.hmap -I/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Documents/code/speedo/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Documents/code/speedo/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -I/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Intermediates/speedo.build/Release-iphoneos/taximeter.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Intermediates/speedo.build/Release-iphoneos/taximeter.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Documents/code/speedo/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -F/Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Documents/code/speedo -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isystem /Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Documents/code/speedo/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem /Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Documents/code/speedo/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -MD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/speedometer-Prefix-copscroeimdxfkdvcsfifjmzires/speedometer-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Documents/code/speedo/speedometer/speedometer-Prefix.pch -o /Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/speedometer-Prefix-copscroeimdxfkdvcsfifjmzires/speedometer-Prefix.pch.pch --serialize-diagnostics /Users/stanislavdvoychenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/speedo-gagyicfwqpzsudcvwgxjqhwbgpte/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/speedometer-Prefix-copscroeimdxfkdvcsfifjmzires/speedometer-Prefix.pch.dia

In file included from :334:
:4:10: error: macro name must be an identifier
#define  1
         ^
1 error generated.
```

And here is the .pch file:

```
#import 

#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Enums.h"
#endif
#define APP ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

I've tried already the clean and Xcode restart.

I'll be grateful for any pointers for how can I dig deeper and find where the problem is.

Comment: I had similar problem and it was for enums. Can you update your question with enum from enums.h?

Comment: I deleted the "Enums.h"line and still the same problem remains. It should be something else then. I'd share "Enums.h", but it's quite big. Trying to find meanwhile anything in git history of a project...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the `-D=1` command-line option in the compile command. You have a bad value somewhere in your build settings, probably in Preprocessor Macros or Other C Flags.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much. I have accidentally revisited preprocessor macros in Xcode and for release configuration only I managed to put a space there: TAXI(space)=1, that made several macros from that in Xcode, TAXI and =1. Thus that -D=1. Thank you for your eagle sharp eyes and wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever content you showed in your `.pch` file looks good; it gets compiled correctly for me. However, compiler is complaining for below code where there is no name given for the macro. `#define` must be followed by macro name whereas in your statement it is missing. Could you please search for `#define 1` statement in your codebase and correct it.

```
In file included from :334:
:4:10: error: macro name must be an identifier
#define  1
```

As a side note, please ensure you do not have any pre processor value set for `APP` like `APP` set to `1`. To rule out, try using a different variable than `APP`.