# C macro name must be an identifier

Tags: c, macros

I've created a c project and this is the beginning of the main.c file:

```c
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "include/httpdef.h"
//...some code
```

The httpdef.h beginning is this:

```
#ifndef httpdef
#define httpdef
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
//definitions
#endif
```

At the very first line of both files I get the error from the gcc compiler:

> macro name must be an identifier

What could be the problem?

EDIT: I realized now that actually the compiler doesn't give any error, it's my vim plugin (YouCOmpleteMe) that generates this error. If I compile everything works and the error doesn't appear

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show us the _verbatim_ error message. Also try to replace `httpdef` by `__httpdef__h__` in the `httpdef.h` file

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807537/xcode-7-macro-name-must-be-an-identifier) suggests that it might also be a good idea to look at your command line / build process.

Comment: I think this answer in C++ would help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426736/error-macro-names-must-be-identifiers-using-ifdef-0

Comment: @Jabberwocky: `httpdef` should not be replaced by `__httpdef__h__`. Identifiers beginning with two underscores are reserved for use by the C implementation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It compiles ok. Please provide more information about your error message and the way you compiled it.

Comment: In my first comment: `__httpdef__h__` -> `_httpdef_h_`.

Comment: I do like guards of type `HTTPDEF_H_INCLUDED` (and they stand out)

Comment: as for @Federico - try *preprocessing* this file only with  `gcc -E`

Comment: Sorry guys, I just found out that actually the compiler is ok, it's my vim plugin (YouCompleteMe) that shows me this error.